# Why using assert.equal intead of using a condition to handle errors in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have copied this code from the mongodb official driver for node.js [quick start page](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/).

```
var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {

    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('documents');

    // Find some documents
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {

        // the line bellow is what I'm asking about
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(docs)
        callback(docs);
    });
}
```

**My question:** is it recommended to use `assert.equal(err, null)` to handle errors instead of using an `if` condition like so:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

is there any differences between the two, or it is just a matter of preference ?

Comment: I believe that's only for testing/demo purposes, which shouldn't be the case with production code where you are expected to have better error handling mechanisms.

Comment: you mean that neither `assert` nor `if condition` are good for production. Could you tell me what kind of error handling mechanisms should I use for production code ?

Comment: This could help https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors